# C++ Print days, hours, minutes, etc. of a chrono::duration

Tags: c++, c++-chrono

I have the following code:

```
// #includes for <chrono>, <iostream>, etc.

using namespace std;
using namespace chrono;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    auto sysStart = system_clock::now();

    LogInit();  // Opens a log file for reading/writing
    // Last shutdown time log entry is marked by a preceding null byte
    logFile.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\0');

    if (logFile.fail() || logFile.bad()) {
        // Calls GetLastError() and logs the error code and message
        LogError("main");
    }

    // Parse the timestamp at the start of the shutdown log entry
    tm end = { 0 };
    logFile >> get_time(&end, "[%d-%m-%Y %T");

    if (logFile.fail() || logFile.bad()) {
        // Same as above. Param is name of function within which error occurred
        LogError("main");
    }

    // Finally, we have the last shutdown time as a chrono::time_point
    auto sysEnd = system_clock::from_time_t(mktime(&end));

    // Calculate the time for which the system was inactive
    auto sysInactive = sysStart - sysEnd;
    auto hrs = duration_cast<hours>(sysInactive).count();
    auto mins = duration_cast<minutes>(sysInactive).count() - hrs * 60;
    auto secs = duration_cast<seconds>(sysInactive).count() - (hrs * 3600) - mins * 60;
    auto ms = duration_cast<milliseconds>(sysInactive).count() - (hrs * 3600000)
        - (mins * 60000) - secs * 1000;

    return 0;
}
```

It works but it's pretty ugly and way too verbose for my liking. Any simpler way to do this **using only STL functions?**

Comment: please include at least a declaration of `sysStart` and `sysEnd`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

When you cannot use [{fmt}](https://fmt.dev/latest/index.html) or wait for C++20 `<format>`, you at least want to delay the invocation of `cout()` on durations as much as possible. Also, let `<chrono>` handle the computation for you. Both measures improve the terseness of the snippet:

```
const auto hrs = duration_cast<hours>(sysInactive);
const auto mins = duration_cast<minutes>(sysInactive - hrs);
const auto secs = duration_cast<seconds>(sysInactive - hrs - mins);
const auto ms = duration_cast<milliseconds>(sysInactive - hrs - mins - secs);
```

And the output:

```
cout << "System inactive for " << hrs.count() <<
    ":" << mins.count() <<
    ":" << secs.count() <<
    "." << ms.count() << endl;
```

Note that you could also define a utility template,

```
template <class Rep, std::intmax_t num, std::intmax_t denom>
auto chronoBurst(std::chrono::duration<Rep, std::ratio<num, denom>> d)
{
    const auto hrs = duration_cast<hours>(d);
    const auto mins = duration_cast<minutes>(d - hrs);
    const auto secs = duration_cast<seconds>(d - hrs - mins);
    const auto ms = duration_cast<milliseconds>(d - hrs - mins - secs);

    return std::make_tuple(hrs, mins, secs, ms);
}
```

that has a nice use case in conjunction with structured bindings:

```
const auto [hrs, mins, secs, ms] = chronoBurst(sysInactive);
```

Comment: Oops. I missed the fact that [std::formatter<std::chrono::duration>](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/duration/formatter) is a C++20 feature. ;-) The linked article seems still to be incomplete.

Comment: Nice! I especially like the utility template; I've been out of the C++ loop for quite a while so didn't even know you could do stuff like tuples etc. Thanks! :D

Comment: Nice answer but I think the extracted millisecond count will be too large because the `- mins` is missing when computing `ms`.